# where is designer view (the 'structure' tab) of the preference activity in android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

in **eclipse ADT plugin** when i create a **preference activity** it provides two modes **design view** and the **xml file** of the preference activity. The design view had the tab name **"structure"** that provides the easy adding of values to attributes through certain input boxes. But in **android studio** i can create an android XML file to create an activity but i cannot find the designer view of the activity, the "structure" tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its no longer available and in android you have to do it manually i.e.write elements and attributes set values. Do it in the same XML file.